# Why ajax not working after uploading on the server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

[image: POST 500 Internal Server Error]

Problem :
This is what I want :
When the link “Register” i.e “1” is clicked, a modal window opens. Therein after filling all the details and after pressing button “Signup” i.e “2” all data should be saved into database and the place where “Please wait…” is shown, it should show “Done” which will happen only when the process completed successfully
This is what’s happening :
After all the required details are filled and when the “Signup” button is clicked, a message is flashed on the screen showing “Something is wrong”. After through checking I came to the conclusion that “ajax part is not working”.  The same code is working perfectly on my localhost ie on my system but after uploading it is showing error : " 500 Internal Server Error". Code is shown below :

```
                        <div class="modal-footer form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <div id="regmesg" class="supmsg pull-left"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" id="btnmodsignup" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="InsSignup()">Signup</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Code of InsSignup() function :

```
            function InsSignup(){   // Sign up Button 
            alert("1");
            $('#cboxtc').prop("checked", false);
            $('#btnmodsignup').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#regmesg').html('Please wait....');
            alert("2");
            var catg = $.trim($('#catgddl').val()); 
            var emailid = $.trim($('#userid').val());
            var fname = $.trim($('#fullname').val());
            var passw = $.trim($('#pwd').val());
            data = {catgddl:catg, userid:emailid, fullname:fname, pwd:passw};
            alert("3");
            $.ajax({
                url : "signupins.php",
                type: "post",
                data: data,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(data){
                    alert("Something is not working");
                }
            });
        }
```

Code for "Signupins.php" :

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/init.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/helpers/helpers.php';

require_once 'lib/Mail.php';
require_once 'lib/mime.php';

var_dump($_POST);
```

?>

In the InsSignup  function, upto alert "3" it works fine, but after that message pops up "Something went wrong". Why ??

I am not able to understand where I am wrong. From the past 7 days I am trying to figure out what's the problem but couldn't  get  it.
Please help ?

Comment: `500 Internal Server Error` suggests that the php code has an error somewhere. Try putting `exit('ok');` statements in the php code before each included file - if it reaches the `ok` move it to the next location and try again - looks likely that one of those `includes` has a syntax error

Comment: and (continueing @RamRaider's comment:) look at "Response" in Network Tab to see what errors your scripts might throw.

Comment: What do you see in the error log?